# Combining conditional probability with combinatorics?

Tags: probability

Im not sure about the following question:

15 (a) What is the probability that your bridge partner has exactly two aces, given that she has at least one ace?

(b) What is the probability that your bridge partner has exactly two aces, given that she has the ace of spades?

The answer is that it is a) $$\frac{\binom{48}{11}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{13}-\binom{48}{13}}$$

b)$$\frac{\binom{48}{11}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{51}{12}}$$

Could someone explain why this is so, and is it possible to not use binomial here, I would like to understand the logic of so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a. A bridge hand has 13 cards.  First, you need to figure out the number of hands with exactly two aces. There are 4 aces to choose from, and your hand has two, so there are $4 \choose 2$ ways to select the two aces. The other cards are not aces, so you are choosing those 11 from the 48 cards that aren't aces $48 \choose 11$. Therefore, there are 
$${48 \choose 11} {4 \choose 2}$$
possible hands with exactly two aces.

We then need to figure out the total number of possible hands with at least one ace. This is the same thing as figuring out the number of possible hands with no aces, and subtracting that from the total number of possible hands:
$$ {52 \choose 13} - {48 \choose 13}.$$

So, the probability of getting a hand with exactly 2 aces, given you have one ace is 
$$\frac{{48 \choose 11} {4 \choose 2}}{{52 \choose 13} - {48 \choose 13}},$$
the total number of hands with exactly two aces divided by the total number of possible hands.

b. We can use similar logic here. Now we know that one one card is the ace of spades, so we have to figure out the number of possible configurations of the other 12 cards. If you have exactly 2 aces, one of the other cards must be an ace, and there are 3 possible aces it could be, so there are ${3 \choose 1}$ way of selecting the other ace. Then there are $48 \choose 11$ ways of selecting the other 11 cards. So there are
$${3 \choose 1}{48 \choose 11}$$ 
hands with exactly two aces given one of the cards is the ace of spades. There are a total of 
$${51 \choose 12}$$ 
possible hands that have the ace of spades, since the number of 13 card hands with the ace of spades is equivalent to the number of ways we could select the other 12 cards in the hand. So, the probability is
$$\frac{{3 \choose 1}{48 \choose 11}}{{51 \choose 12}}.$$

The binomial coefficients give you an easy and convenient way of counting the number of possible hands that satisfy the desired property.